# I'm not able to process data through awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I'm trying to process data using awk but I'm not able to achieve the right result.Please let know If doing wrong somewhere
Data:- test.txt

```
"A","B","ls",,"This,is,the,test",T,
"k",O,"mv",,"This,is,the,2nd test","L",
"C",J,"cd",,"This,is,the,3rd test",,

awk  'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="|" }  { nf=0; delete f; while ( match($0,/([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")/) ) { f[++nf] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH); };  print f[2],f[3],f[4],f[5] }' test.txt
```

Ouput

```
"B"|"ls"|"This,is,the,test"|T
O|"mv"|"This,is,the,2nd test"|"L"
J|"cd"|"This,is,the,3rd test"|
```

But output should be like this

```
"B"|"ls"||"This,is,the,test"|T
O|"mv"||"This,is,the,2nd test"|"L"
J|"cd"||"This,is,the,3rd test"|
```

Comment: Why do you bother to set `FS` if you never access any of the fields?

Comment: Why don't you expect `"A"`  to be in the output? There's nothing in your script that skips the first field.

Comment: Is your question really about why you don't get the empty `||` field?

Comment: That's because `[^,]+` requires that the field have at least one character between commas.

Comment: Now I don't understand even more. When I tried it, I got the version of the output before you edited.

Comment: @Barmar could you check now?

Comment: OK, it's like I said: your regexp doesn't match empty fields.

Comment: How about this `awk  'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="|" }  { nf=0; delete f; while ( match($0,/((?<=,)(.*)(?=,))|(\"[^\"]+\")/) ) { f[++nf] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH); };  print f[2],f[3],"",f[4],f[5] }' file`

Comment: I see you just updated your input to include fields that don't have double quotes. Do you have any other major surprises to tell us about, e.g. newlines and/or escaped quotes within quoted fields?

Comment: @Ed Morton This is last update.

Comment: OK I posted a solution that will work with any awk and handles your new input, including deleting the first and last fields as you now require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your new input and any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="|" }
{
    # 1) Replace all FSs inside quotes with the value of RS
    #    since we know that RS cannot be present in any record:
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while( match(tail,/"[^"]+"/) ) {
        trgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(FS,RS,trgt)
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) trgt
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $0 = head tail

    # 2) re-compile the record to replace FSs with OFSs:
    $1 = $1

    # 3) restore the RSs within quoted fields to FSs:
    gsub(RS,FS)

    # 4) remove the first and last fields:
    gsub("^[^" OFS "]*[" OFS "]|[" OFS "][^" OFS "]*$","")

    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"B"|"ls"||"This,is,the,test"|T
O|"mv"||"This,is,the,2nd test"|"L"
J|"cd"||"This,is,the,3rd test"|
```

Comment: It is not possible I can resolve through with same version which is I have.

Comment: It's possible, just more work. You're using an EXTREMELY old awk btw, you should really upgrade it as you're missing a ton of very useful functionality (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History). Can you upgrade your awk version?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\" '{q="\""; print q$4q"|"q$6q"||"q$8q}'
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply suposse I hv records i have update above.I have remove the double quote from second column  plz let me know how can I process the file.

Comment: This solution assumes all of your non-empty values are double quoted. Perhaps you could update your input sample to clarify the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vFPAT='"[^"]*"' '{$0=$2"|"$3"||"$4}1' FILE
```

use pat

Comment: Or IMHO more simply and awkishly `awk -vFPAT='"[^"]*"' -vOFS='|' '{print $2, $3, "", $4}' file`. Note that use of `FPAT` requires GNU awk.